# How do I determine external monitor color bit depth (8 vs 10) in macOS 12 / Monterey?

Tags: display, color

The framebuffer depth statement is gone from "System Report". I can scan through the output of `system_profiler` and find the section for my external display where it says `"ColorElements"={..."Depth"=0x8...}`. Does that mean 8-bit? Does this show even when a display uses 8-bit + FRC, or is macOS *only* registering/using 8-bit color?

(This is all in the service of diagnosing why I'm seeing weird colors in the extreme parts of the spectrum and whether that's due to the 120/144Hz refresh rate but stands as a useful-seeming question on its own as I couldn't find a modern answer.)